# create react project error socket_timeout

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image]

help me with this issue. i am new one

I tried to create my react app. I was expecting that it will be done smoothly but it didn't. My internet connection is also stable but I don't know why this error occurs.

Comment: Try to clear npm cache by run `npm  cache clear --force`

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, firewall, or VPN that could be limiting your access to npm? Are you able to start a new project and `npm i` a module without any problems (for example, `mkdir test-issue && cd test-issue && npm init -y && npm i react`)?